# How to resolve issue with "undefined" variables in Vue component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to manipulate data from an array in Vue.js, specifically trying to simply print out a variable value, since I can not get even that to work for now.

I have tried different syntax to make it work but it seems data is not attached yet.

````
  el: '#profile',
  delimiters: ['${','}'],
  data: {
    component: null,
    component_info:  null,
    loading: true,
    fields: [
        ],
  },
  beforeMount: function(){
    this.whatever2=document.getElementsByClassName('token-carrier')[0].getAttribute('token') || '';
 },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getComponent();
  },
  computed: function(){
    console.log(this.component['name'].value); //value is undefined
  },
  methods: {
    getComponent: function() {
      let api_url = '/api/component/' + '?' + 'id=' + this.whatever2;
      this.loading = true;

      this.$http.get(api_url)
          .then((response) => {
            this.component = response.data[0];
            this.loading = false;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            this.loading = false;
            console.log(err);
          })
    },
  }
});```
````

Comment: the property `computed` should be a object not a function like `methods`

Answer (score 0):

used `created()` method and inside this, call `this.getComponent();`

```
 created: function() {
    this.getComponent();
  },
```

UPDATE:
 there are ather problem

```
 this.component = response.data[0];
```

this line has error, becouse `this` keyword does not indicate your scope,
try this:

```
      var that = this;

      this.$http.get(api_url)
          .then((response) => {
            that.component = response.data[0];
            that.loading = false;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            that.loading = false;
            console.log(err);
          })
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, nothing changes with the problem.

Comment: Seems like another problem, I updated my comment, please check

Comment: Sadly it still says  "component is not defined" in console.

Comment: why you use 'computed' like function? console place is not here, delete this and log after fetch data in getComponent function= >  that.component = response.data[0]; console.log( that.component['name'].value)